# Identity - Authenticate API using OpenId Connect (ID Token and Access Token)

Tags: oauth, postman, openid-connect, identity

I have a request where I am calling an API which has to be authenticated before use and supports Openid Connect. I am confused why I need to use OIDC for this. Will OAuth alone not solve this?

My understanding is my access token will be used to access the API (protected resource), and it only cares about authorisation not authentication. Why/how will the Id token be used when I call the API? I can use bearer access token on Postman so where does the ID Token fit into this?

From what I have seen, Id tokens are meant for the client application to validate a users information. Then the client application can create a session Id for that user so they can login.

My application calling --> External Systems API

Comment: Can you provide more details about the API and the requests that you have already tried to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people that can answer this will be the people behind whatever API you're calling. We can only guess at what they're doing with that info.

But, yes, you're pretty much on the mark for OAuth and OIDC. OAuth is an authorization framework and OIDC adds authentication on top of that.